# Max or min depending on another variable

Tags: r, variables, max, min

I need to calculate the max and min of the wave height according to the direction from which it comes, that is to say, I have two variables:

- Hs (wave height)
- Direction (direction of the swell)

And I need to know the maximum wave height for waves with a direction between 11.25 and 33.75 degrees.

For now, use the function:

```
Max (Hs [Direction [11.25: 33.75]))
```

But I do not agree the result with the data that I have.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please give a [mcve] ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Have a look at `dput()`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume your dataframe is called `df`, your variables are called `Hs` and `Direction`, you can use

```
max(df$Hs[df$Direction >= 11.25 & df$Direction <= 33.75])
```

to get the maximum of all `Hs` values within the defined value range of `Direction`.

If you, like me, dislike the necessity to define both lower and upper bounds of the interval separately, you can use this neat function (which I found [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/screen-if-a-value-is-within-range-td4651562.html)):

```
in_interval <- function(x, interval){
   stopifnot(length(interval) == 2L)
   interval[1] < x & x < interval[2]
}
```

Then use

```
max(df$Hs[in_interval(df$Direction, c(11.25, 33.75))])
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @LAP is absolutely correct, but you can also use the `dplyr` package to get both the `max` and `min`.

First let's create some sample data.

```
df <- data.frame(Hs = rnorm(327), Direction = runif(327, 0, 364))
```

Now let's calculate.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(Direction >= 11.25 & Direction <= 33.75) %>% 
  summarise(max(Hs), min(Hs))
```